# BadMethodCallException on laravel authentication

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I'm trying to make an authentication in laravel with multiple tables to separate user roles, is an academic exercise, so I can't do it any other way.

```
BadMethodCallException
Method App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController::create does not exist.
```

This error comes up when I try to register a user in the database. I understand that this is when the redirection occurs.

So... these are my routes from web.php:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers;


Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
}); 

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');


Route::get('/login/admin', [App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController::class,'showAdminLoginForm']);
Route::get('/login/user', [App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController::class,'showUserLoginForm']); 
Route::get('/register/admin', [App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController::class,'showAdminRegisterForm']);
Route::get('/register/user', [App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController::class,'showUserRegisterForm']);

Route::post('/login/admin', [App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController::class,'adminLogin']);
Route::post('/login/user', [App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController::class,'userLogin']);
Route::post('/register/admin', [App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController::class,'createAdmin']);
Route::post('/register/user', [App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController::class,'createUser']);

Route::view('/home', 'home')->middleware('auth');
Route::view('/admin', 'admin');
Route::view('/user', 'user');
```

This is the RegisterController from App\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use App\Models\User;
use App\Models\Admin;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{

    use RegistersUsers;

    protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
        $this->middleware('guest:admin');
        $this->middleware('guest:user');
    }

    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
        ]);
    }

    //USER STUFF
    protected function createUser(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validator($request->all())->validate();
        $user = User::create([
            'username' => $request['username'],
            'name' => $request['name'],
            'email' => $request['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($request['password']),
        ]);
        return redirect()->intended('login/user');
    }

    public function showUserRegisterForm()
    {
        return view('auth.register', ['url' => 'user']);
    }

    //ADMIN STUFF
    protected function createAdmin(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validator($request->all())->validate();
        $admin = Admin::create([
            'username' => $request['username'],
            'name' => $request['name'],
            'email' => $request['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($request['password']),
        ]);
        return redirect()->intended('login/admin');
    }

    public function showAdminRegisterForm()
    {
        return view('auth.register', ['url' => 'admin']);
    }

}
```

Also I think that this is necessary, the auth.php file, where guards are defined:

```
    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],


    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
            'hash' => false,
        ],
        'admin' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'admins',
            'hash' => false,
        ],
        'user' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
            'hash' => false,
        ],
        
    ],



    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\User::class,
        ],

        'admins' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\Admin::class,
        ],

        // 'users' => [
        //     'driver' => 'database',
        //     'table' => 'users',
        // ],
    ],
```

Models for user and admin:

User:

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasFactory, Notifiable;

    protected $guard = 'user';
    protected $fillable = [
        'username',
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}
```

Admin:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasFactory, Notifiable;
    
    protected $guard = 'admin';
    protected $fillable = [
        'username',
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}
```

I'm not sure if I forgot something, but I've been stuck in the same error for several hours and I can't see what I'm doing wrong... In any case I will edit this with the necessary information if I have forgotten something.

> In case it is necessary and to provide more information that I think is important, I'll add the link to the tutorial that I've been following, if someone knows how to fix it, or finds the bug.
> https://pusher.com/tutorials/multiple-authentication-guards-laravel

Comment: Your controller includes a trait: `use RegistersUsers;` Check the methods in it to see if one of them calls `create()` method. The error message you're partly including here also has the line number where the error happens...

Comment: initially I don't see any create() method in RegisterUsers() except in line 34 where there is `event(new Registered($user = $this->create($request->all())));`. which is inside `function register(Request $request){  [...]  }`

Comment: You will need to override the `register()` method from RegistersUsers trait in your RegisterController. The register method in the trait calls create() method on RegisterController. Since you have createUser and createAdmin instead of create, you will need to override register method in your controller

Comment: I think that's not the solution, if you look at the tutorial I put at the end, it doesn't have any kind of override of any method, the creation of users is done through a model in 
`User::create([...]);`

Comment: Okay. Just remove `Auth::routes()` from the routes file. The route declarations by the `Auth::routes()` is before your custom registration routes and hence take precedence. That's why you are hitting the create() method. Remove Auth::routes and it should work as per the turorial

Comment: Or just exclude the register and login routes from routes generated by Auth::routes(), by `Auth::routes(['register' => false, 'login' => false])` then it will generate routes only for password reset, email verification and password confirmation